# How to validate this using Regex C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a input which can be the following (Either one of these three):

- 1-8…in other words 1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8
- A-Z….in other words, A, B, C, D etc
- 01-98…in other words, 01,02,03,04 etc

I came up with this regex but it's not working not sure why:

```
@"[A-Z0-9][1-8]-
```

I am thinking to check for corner cases like just 0 and just 9 after regex check because regex check isn't validating this

Comment: So it can be only one of those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I understand, but how about:

```
^(?:[A-Z]|[1-8]|0[1-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-8])$
```

**Explanation:**

`(?:...)` is a group without capture.
`|` introduces an alternative
`[A-Z]` means one letter
`[1-8]` one digit between 1 and 8
`0[1-9]` a 0 followed by a digit between 1 and 9
`[1-8][0-9]` a digit between 1 and 8 followed by a digit between 1 and 9
`9[0-8]` 9 followed by a digit between 0 and 8

May be it is, depending on your real needs:

```
^(?:[A-Z]|[0-9]?[1-8])$
```

Comment: @M42, ^(?:[A-Z]|[1-8]|0[1-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-8])$ seems to work. Is it possible for you to explain a bit how is it working?

Comment: I would personally use your first regex with a slight modification: `^(?:[A-Z]|0[1-9]|[1-8][0-9]?|9[0-8])$` That should cover everything the second one fails to.

Comment: @Jerry: You're right for the first one. For the second regex, I supposed OP wanted only numbers that end with digit between 1 and 8 as it's not really clear in the question.

Comment: @M42, Thanks m42. Just 1 question, what does "is a group without capture mean?"

Comment: Yes, that wasn't entirely clear indeed. Only @Charu can confirm this.

Comment: @Charu: It acts like a group but it's not available by say `$1` as a capture group is. It's more efficient if you don't need the capture.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may use this pattern

```
@"^([1-8A-Z]|0[1-9]|[1-9]{2})$"
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `^([1-8]|([0-9][0-9])|[A-Z])$` ?

That will give a match for

A
8 (but not 9)
09

Answer (score 0):

You can use following pattern:

```
^[1-8][A-Z](?:0[1-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-8])$
```

- `^[1-8]` - input should start with number 1-8
- `[A-Z]` - then should be single letter A-Z
- `(0[1-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-8])$` and it should end with two numbers which are 01-19 or 10-89 or 90-98

Test:

```
string pattern = @"^[1-8][A-Z](0[1-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-8])$";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
string[] valid = { "1A01", "8Z98" };
bool allMatch = valid.All(regex.IsMatch);
string[] invalid = { "0A01", "11A01", "1A1", "1A99", "1A00", "101", "1AA01" };
bool allNotMatch = !invalid.Any(regex.IsMatch);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[1-8]{0,1}[A-Z]{0,1}\d{1,2}
```

matches all of the following

```
8A8 8B9 9 0 00
```